# userContent.css to get fixed width font in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, gmail

I am trying to get a fixed-width monospace font in gmail's new compose feature in firefox using a bit of css in userContent.css.  Something like the following used to do the trick for me:

```
@-moz-document domain(mail.google.com)
{
  .ii, .Ak, .editable, .LW-avf
  {
    font-family: monospace !important;
    font-size: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

but it no longer works.  Using the inspect element in firefox I see that the message is in something like:

```
<body id=":di" class="editable LW-avf"
```

Is there something I am missing here?  Why is a compose window not `monospace` if it is in class `editable` and `LW-avf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a closer look at the gmail html, it looks like they are using an iframe with the html explicitly embedded... I have never seen this before.  Something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe>
      #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <body id=":di" class="editable LW-avf">
              ...
            </body>
          </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Presumably, the `@-moz-document domain(mail.google.com)` doesn't match the url for the page in the iframe (not sure what the URL would even be).

If I don't match the url then it works fine.  Of course, now the style will be applied to any page with a class named `editable`.

I may take this up with the mozilla developers when I find time.

Answer (score 3):

I guessed that the iframe will not have any domain associated with it. This seems to work for viewing and composing messages:

```
@-moz-document domain(mail.google.com) {
    .gs .ii {
        font-family: monospace !important;
        font-size: 100% !important;
    }
}
@-moz-document domain() {
    .editable.LW-avf {
        font-family: monospace !important;
        font-size: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but won't this apply a monospace font to ANY web page that has a class named .editable?

Comment: I tested this and the style is only applied to pages that don't have a domain. The iframe is one such case, local pages (file://) is another. If you remove "@-moz-document domain()" completely, then the style will apply everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see, clever.  Still not perfect, but better than what I had!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, but can't check the specifics as I dropped GMail some time ago (google was getting too freaky with pushing social networking...)

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#used-value

On the cascade order it says that Author mode trumps user mode. Unless user !important. Which you are using.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

And here it says that the more specific gets applied.

for example:

```
div#d.bclass { color: green; }
.aclass { color: red; }

<div id=d class="aclass bclass">hello world</div>
```

The div will be green all day long. But I bet you already know that.

What may be happening, is that the browser is choosing some author rule that has much more specificity than yours. which is a bug...Can you look at the Inspector and see where the computed font comes from?